# finding plus "+" character with number like +90 90+ in string

Tags: php, preg-replace, preg-match

I tried so many preg_replace and preg_match codes but i cant do.
I try to find strings contain +18 , 18+ or (+18)
I cant explain but you can understand when see my codes.

```
//inputs 
$product='example: 18 kg apple'; // my hope output: EVERYONE
$product='water pipe (18) meters'; // my hope output: EVERYONE
//outputs: OVER 18 

$product='product +18 dress';   // my hope output: OVER 18    
$product='product 18+ dress';   // my hope output: OVER 18
$product='product (+18) dress';     // my hope output: OVER 18
//outputs are already OVER 18 
//Because of contain 18 
//not +18 or 18+. it doesnt work truly


    preg_match('/\b(\w*18\w*)\b/', $product, $match);

        if( $match[1]=='+18' || $match[1]=='18+' ) { 

                echo "OVER 18<br>"; 
    }
       else{
               echo "EVERYONE<br>";

                }
```

Comment: Try `preg_match('~\+18\b|\b18\+~', $s, $m)`

Comment: it works thanks bro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this simple case, I wouldn't use an regex. Just using `strpos` would also do the job.

```
if (strpos($product, '18+') !== false || strpos($product, '+18') !== false) {
    // over 18
}
```

Comment: Yes, but it will return true if it finds `+180` and `180+`.

Comment: thanks bro. perfect answer exactly as I want. yes it's false at +180 and 180+ but it's enough for me. i dont suppose i meet a product contains +180 or 180+. i hope i dont

Answer (score 1):

Use this: `(\+18|18\+)`- it checks if `+18` or `18+` exists in the string.

So something like this:
`preg_match('(\+18|18\+)', $product, $match);` should work.

Only tested it here https://regex101.com/ (a very good place to test regexp